# Patching Mach-o Binary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking for a way to patch Mach-o Binaries, although I've come up short of possible (and not too tedious) ways of accomplishing this. I'm very familiar with hex editing and patching bytes by hand, although ultimately what I really need is a way to create a drag'n'drop method of doing this via a compiled Xcode Cocoa application.

Any example, or even better, an actual usable Xcode project template to get start would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to do this kind of thing, I'd start with [HexFiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/).  Then I'd look up the implementation of [dyld](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/dyld.1.html) and otool in the [Darwin source repository](http://darwinsource.sourceforge.net/) and the [Mac OS X ABI Mach-O File Format Reference](http://Mac%20OS%20X%20ABI%20Mach-O%20File%20Format%20Reference)

Comment: Out of curiosity why not just a naive binary diff?

Comment: I assumed he wanted to do more than that.  If all he needed was any binary diff tool, then he wouldn't have asked about Mach-O specifically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically deal with the Mach-O file format to access load commands, segments, sections and more, you should use libMachObjC which is part of the [class-dump](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump/) project. The API is very easy to use.

Have a look at the [deprotect](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump/blob/master/deprotect.m) tool source code for an example of reading a Mach-O file, patching some bytes and writing the modified file to disk.